# syntax error near unexpected token `fi' - High load Notification mail

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

Im trying to get the server to email me if the load goes above 15, but i keep getting the following error.

> ```
> root@echo [~]# sh load.sh
> load.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
> load.sh: line 9: `fi'
> ```

Here is the load.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
SUBJECT="`hostname`server load is high"
TO=myemail@gmail.com
uptime > /tmp/load
if [ `uptime | awk '{ print$11 }' | cut -d. -f1` -gt 1 ];
then
mail -s "$SUBJECT" $TO < /tmp/load
exit
fi
```

Server uname -a

Linux 2.6.18-308.24.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Dec 4 17:43:34 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get the same error than you but you can already test this solution:

```
if [ `uptime | awk '{ print$11 }' | cut -d. -f1` -gt 1 ];
```

This condition try to compare a float with an integer. I would make this test with [an extended  test command](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html). And you can forget semicolon if you don't put `then` keyword on the same line than your condition :

```
if [[ `uptime | awk '{ print$11 }' | cut -d. -f1` > 1 ]]
then
   mail -s "$SUBJECT" $TO < /tmp/load
   exit
fi
```

Comment: I changed it to be as you posted but now i am receiving a different error when i try to run it.
root@echo [~]# sh load.sh
load.sh: line 5: syntax error in conditional expression
'oad.sh: line 5: syntax error near `]]
'oad.sh: line 5: `if [[ `uptime | awk '{ print$11 }' | cut -d. -f1` > 1 ]]

Comment: My last arrow: You declare to use /bin/bash as interpreter, but in your post you seem to invoke it with `sh` instead of `bash`. And you use features only present in `bash`